# Case based If then statements in a userform

Tags: excel, vba, combobox, case

Scenario 1: If Combobox 2 displays the same text/value currently in the 
worksheet MRFL Range(A1:A250) and combobox 1 displays the same text/value as in worksheet MFRL Range(B1:B250) then only change the value of column AE in the same row as the combobox 2 value in Worksheet MFGLR.

Scenario 2: If Combobox 2 displays the same text/value currently in the worksheet MRFL Range(A1:A250) and combobox 1 displays a different text then in worksheet MFRL Range(B1:B250) then add the values of combobox1 and combobox2 at the next available row in worksheet MFRL, Combobox1 in column B and Combobox2 in column A. And then only change the value of column AE in the same row as the combobox 2 value in Worksheet MFGLR.

Scenario 3: If Combobox 2 displays a different text/value currently in the worksheet MRFL Range(A1:A250) and combobox 1 displays a different text then in worksheet MFRL Range(B1:B250) then add the values of combobox1 and combobox2 at the next available row in worksheet MFRL, add combobox2 value at the next available row in Column A in the worksheet CT and add the combobox 2 value in the next available row in Column A of worksheet MFGLR Combobox1 in column B and Combobox2 in column A. And then only change the value of column AE in the same row as the combobox 2 value in Worksheet MFGLR.

For Scenarios 1 and 2, I'm having trouble having the code find the same row as combobox2 value and then pasting the textbox1 value 31 columns to the right as that. This is what I have so far.

```
With Worksheets("MFGLR").Range("a1:a500")
Set C = .Find(ComboBox2.Value, LookIn:=xlValues)
If Not C Is Nothing Then
firstAddress = C.Address
Do
    C.Value = TextBox1.Value
    Set C = .FindNext(C)
Loop While Not C Is Nothing
End If
End With
```

1. The scenarios don't seem to be holding true for all the cases
2. I would like the border of CT to go from the lastrow Column A to Column V
3. I would like the border of MFRL to go from lastrow Column A to Column E
4. I would like the border of MFRL to go from lastrow Column A to Column AM
5. Fill down from the last row in MFGLR column AF to column AH

This is my WIP for all the scenarios with borders and filldown.

```
Option Explicit
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim ColA As New Scripting.Dictionary  'Need Microsoft Scripting Runtime Reference
Dim ColB As New Scripting.Dictionary
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim Criteria1 As Boolean
Dim Criteria2 As Boolean
Dim C As Range



With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("MFRL")
    LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row 'This gets the last row on column A
    For Each C In .Range("A1:A" & LastRow) 'loop through the whole column
    On Error Resume Next
        'If you have duplicated entries this will throw an error
        ColA.Add C.Value, C.Row 'add the values from column A to DictA, also store it's row for later purposes
        ColB.Add C.Offset(0, 1).Value, C.Row 'add the values from column B to DictB, also store it's row for later purposes
    Next C
    'Criterias will give value of True if matched or False if not
    Criteria1 = ColA.Exists(ComboBox2.Value) 'this is getting matched with ColA Dictionary
    Criteria2 = ColB.Exists(ComboBox1.Value) 'this is getting matched with ColB Dictionary
    If Criteria1 And Criteria2 Then 'SCENARIO 1
        .Cells(ColA(ComboBox2.Value), "AE:100") = TextBox1.Value
    ElseIf Criteria1 And Not Criteria2 Then 'SCENARIO 2
        .Cells(LastRow + 1, 1) = ComboBox2.Value
        .Cells(LastRow + 1, 2) = ComboBox1.Value
        .Cells(ColA(ComboBox2.Value), "AE") = TextBox1.Value
    With Worksheets("MFRL")
        .Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Offset(-1, 1).Resize(, 3).AutoFill .Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Offset(-1, 1).Resize(, 3).Resize(2)
        .Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Offset(-1, 1).Resize(, 3).Resize(2).Borders.LineStyle = xlContinuous
        End With
    ElseIf Not Criteria1 And Not Criteria2 Then 'SCENARIO 3
        .Cells(LastRow + 1, 1) = ComboBox2.Value
        .Cells(LastRow + 1, 2) = ComboBox1.Value
        'Add data to the column A next blank row in sheet CT
        LastRow = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("CT").Cells(ThisWorkbook.Sheets("CT").Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets("CT").Cells(LastRow, 1) = ComboBox2.Value
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets("CT").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(-1, 1).Resize(, 21).AutoFill .Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(-1, 1).Resize(, 21).Resize(2)
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets("CT").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(-1, 1).Resize(, 21).Resize(2).Borders.LineStyle = xlContinuous
        'Add data to the column A next blank row in sheet MFGLR
        LastRow = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("MFGL R").Cells(ThisWorkbook.Sheets("MFGLR").Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets("MFGLR").Cells(LastRow, 1) = ComboBox2.Value
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets("MFGLR").Cells(LastRow, "AE") = TextBox1.Value
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets("MFGLR").Cells(Rows.Count, "AE").End(xlUp).Offset(-1, 1).Resize(, 3).AutoFill .Cells(Rows.Count, "AE").End(xlUp).Offset(-1, 1).Resize(, 3).Resize(2)
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets("MFGLR").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(-1, 1).Resize(, 38).Resize(2).Borders.LineStyle = xlContinuous
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets("MFRL").Cells(LastRow, 1) = ComboBox2.Value
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets("MFRL").Cells(LastRow, 2) = ComboBox1.Value
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets("MFRL").Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Offset(-1, 1).Resize(, 3).AutoFill .Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Offset(-1, 1).Resize(, 3).Resize(2)
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets("MFRL").Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Offset(-1, 1).Resize(, 3).Resize(2).Borders.LineStyle = xlContinuous
   End If
 End With
 ActiveWorkbook.RefreshAll
 Unload Me
 End Sub
```

Comment: You compare a single string (`ComboBox2.Value`) with a whole range of cells? What is the idea?

Comment: I mean to say if Combobox2.value is = to any cell in that range then...@FunThomas

Comment: I would suggest then store both columns in 2 dictionaries. then check using the property `.Exists`from the dictionary if the `Combobox2.Value` is inside the dictionaries, if so then your code.

Comment: @Damian not exactly sure how to do that, shouldn't the if statement I have work though?

Comment: No, you can't compare a single value to a whole range like this, you need to either loop through the range or as I said, store the ranges into dictionaries and check if your values exists. Also your last line, the one printing the value to the cell doesn't work either. You can't  use  `sheet.range.offset(0, 31)` it should be `Sheets("SheetName").Range("A1").Offset(0, 31)`

Comment: when you say dictionaries do you mean to dim Rng as range dime Rng1 as range then set Rng as Column A and Rng1 as Column B. Where would I then place the .Exist? @Damian

Comment: No, [here](http://www.snb-vba.eu/VBA_Dictionary_en.html) you can read about dictioanries. Dictionaries are collections that let you store one `Key` (Value of each cell in the column) with one `Item`(in this case you can just use 1 as item because you don't need them). Once the Dictionary is built you can check if `Dictionary.Exists(ComboBox2.Value)` that way you don't need to loop through the whole range every time.

Comment: Ok is this close to correct?                                                                                 
 With CreateObject("scripting.dictionary") Set.Item.combobox1.value = Worksheet("MFGLR").range("A1:A250") Set.item.combobox2.value = Worksheet("MFGLR").range("B1:B250") End With                                                     
If Dictionary.Exists(Combobox2.value) and Dictionary.Exists(Combobox1.value) then sheets("MFGLR".range("A1").Offset(0, 31).Value = Textbox1.value   @Damian

Comment: add the code as edit on your question, is hard to read it here.

Comment: Sorry edited @Damian

Comment: if Scenario one occurs I would like the last line of code that I have in my "tried section" to replace the value/text in the same row as the combobox2 value but 31 columns to the right and replace it with the textbox1 value. @Damian

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood all your scenarios ok this should do it, otherwise, please feel free to amend the code:

```
Option Explicit 'always get this, it forces you to declare all your variables
Sub Test()

    Dim ColA As New Scripting.Dictionary  'Need Microsoft Scripting Runtime Reference
    Dim ColB As New Scripting.Dictionary
    Dim LastRow As Long
    Dim Criteria1 As Boolean
    Dim Criteria2 As Boolean
    Dim C As Range


    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("MFGLR")
        LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row 'This gets the last row on column A
        For Each C In .Range("A1:A" & LastRow) 'loop through the whole column
            'If you have duplicated entries this will throw an error
            ColA.Add C.Value, C.Row 'add the values from column A to DictA, also store it's row for later purposes
            ColB.Add C.Offset(0, 1).Value, C.Row 'add the values from column B to DictB, also store it's row for later purposes
        Next C
        'Criterias will give value of True if matched or False if not
        Criteria1 = ColA.Exists(Combobox2.Value) 'this is getting matched with ColA Dictionary
        Criteria2 = ColB.Exists(Combobox1.Value) 'this is getting matched with ColB Dictionary
        If Criteria1 And Criteria2 Then 'SCENARIO 1
            .Cells(ColA(Combobox2.Value), "AE") = Combobox2.Value
        ElseIf Criteria1 And Not Criteria2 Then 'SCENARIO 2
            .Cells(LastRow + 1, 1) = Combobox2.Value
            .Cells(LastRow + 1, 2) = Combobox1.Value
        ElseIf Not Criteria1 And Not Criteria2 Then 'SCENARIO 3
            .Cells(LastRow + 1, 1) = Combobox2.Value
            .Cells(LastRow + 1, 2) = Combobox1.Value
            'Add data to the column A next blank row in sheet CT
            LastRow = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("CT").Cells(ThisWorkbook.Sheets("CT").Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1
            ThisWorkbook.Sheets("CT").Cells(LastRow, 1) = Combobox2.Value
            'Add data to the column A next blank row in sheet MFGLR
            LastRow = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("MFGLR ").Cells(ThisWorkbook.Sheets("MFGLR ").Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1
            ThisWorkbook.Sheets("MFGLR").Cells(LastRow, 1) = Combobox2.Value
            ThisWorkbook.Sheets("MFGLR").Cells(LastRow, 2) = Combobox1.Value
            ThisWorkbook.Sheets("MFGLR").Cells(LastRow + 1, "AE") = Combobox2.Value
        End If
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Trying it now thanks. the field will have duplicates. That being said would On Error Resume Next be ok?

Comment: This has no logic... you are intending on changing a cell if there is a match, there would be 5 matches? change then 5 cells?

Comment: I should have mentioned this in the question but I will be linking Combobox2 to more then one worksheet in my workbook. If criteria 1 and 2 match (Scenario 1) I would like the cell 31 rows over from the combobox2 placement in another sheet to change, not the sheet that has the criteria.

Comment: Then there is no problem.

Comment: I recieve compile error: User-defined type not defined on the first line (Dim ColA as New Scripting.Dictionary

Comment: it is written on the code, you need to check the microsoft scripting runtime library

Comment: Please help Damian

Comment: What do you need help with? @Tmacjoshua

Comment: I'm having trouble having the code find the same row as combobox2 value and then pasting the textbox1 value 31 columns to the right as that. This is what I have so far. This is for scenario 1 and 2. I have posted the code that I have tried in the question

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56367391/in-a-userform-link-textbox-to-the-same-row-as-the-combobox-but-different-column I actually posted it as a new question here as well. Thanks Damian!

Comment: There you have an answer, doesn't it help?

Comment: It did help, but I did the code I have tried does not seem to work. I do not know where to place the .row or .columns to have the textbox1 value be placed 31 columns to the right of the combobox2 value found

Comment: I could post a full question explaining all I am doing if that would be better