# In a Userform, Link Textbox to the same row as the combobox but different Column

Tags: excel, vba, combobox, textbox, userform

I have created a userform with 2 comboboxes, a textbox and a button that will link the comboboxes/textbox depending on the scenario.

For one of the scenarios, if combobox 2, displays the same text/value currently in the worksheet MRFGLR Range Column A change the value of column AE with the textbox value in the same row as the combobox 2 value in Worksheet MFGLR.
In a Userform, Link Textbox to the same row as the combobox but different Column

I'm having trouble having the code find the same row as combobox2 value and then pasting the textbox1 value 31 columns to the right as that. This is what I have so far.

```
With Worksheets("MFGLR").Range("a1:a500")
Set C = .Find(ComboBox2.Value, LookIn:=xlValues)
If Not C Is Nothing Then
    firstAddress = C.Address
    Do
        C.Value = TextBox1.Value
        Set C = .FindNext(C)
    Loop While Not C Is Nothing
End If
End With
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to find which row you need based on the value in "combobox2" would be to use the Range.Find Method. [Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.find) is the documentation from Microsoft on how to use the method. You would pass in the value in "combobox2" as the value to find. It also shows you how to catch an error when you don't find the value you are looking for (which in my experience can happen quite often).

The Range.Find method returns a Range Object, which is basically an address for a cell. From there you could use something like `.Row` to find the row you need and then reference it in combination with your column "AE".

Let me know if this helps! Good Luck!

Comment: Thanks Garrett I will try it out. I think this line of code stores the row. ColB.Add C.Offset(0, 1).Value, C.Row. Could I somehow incorporate that?

Comment: I added in the .range function that you provided. Now where would I place the .row?

Comment: Assuming you have the code working as you would like it to, you would probably create a variable and set it equal to `C.Row`. Then you could do something like, `.Range("AE" & R).Value = Textbox1.Value`. "R" would be the variable you create to store the row. Keep in mind that your textboxes and variables and such might not match what I just typed exactly. Also, your code shows that you set `C.Value` to something else. I haven't tried it myself, but I would think that would override the value that you just found... Good Luck!